# useContext clear when logout function react js

Tags: reactjs

I need to clear `useContext` values in the `logout` function. This is the values:

```js
const [appUserConfig, setAppUserConfig] = useContext(UserContext);
const logout = () => {
    console.log(appUserConfig);
};
```

Below is `console.log` data:

```
{
    accessToken: '...',
    accessTokenName: '...'
}
```

When user click the logout function I need to clear `accessToken` & `accessTokenName`. How can I achieve it?

Comment: `setAppUserConfig({accessToken: null, accessTokenName: null})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const [appUserConfig, setAppUserConfig] = useContext(UserContext);
const logout = () => {
    setAppUserConfig({});
};
```

Or you can `setAppUserConfig({ accessToken: '', accessTokenName: '' });` or `setAppUserConfig({ accessToken: null, accessTokenName: null });` which suit your requirement.