# Clear useContext state on logout

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-context

Whenever I logout on my app (using firebase authentication) and then log back in as a separate user, I notice that some state is preserved from the initial user that I logged out of (which shouldn't happen).

I am guessing this is caused because I did not clear the state in useContext, but I was wondering what the best way to go about doing this was?

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65422098/usecontext-clear-when-logout-function-react-js) but I setup my context API differently and was not sure how to apply it to my case, this is what my context file looks like:

```
const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState();

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{someState, setSomeState}}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve clearing the context on unMount with useEffect. You should be able to add something like this to you useGlobalContext hook

```
useEffect(
  () => (): void => clear my context logic here,
  []
)
```

Comment: would I need to manually clear every single state variable? Is there no shorthand to achieve this?

Comment: Ken that's just because of how you built state within context.  Context is just a holder of state in your case.  If you want to clear all your state variables, you could just put all your state variables into one state object and clear the whole object.